# how to solve global temp table in windows azure

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage, global-temp-tables

i am using global temp in my sql stored procedure when i upload into azure it is not working, can anyone please help me to solve this issue

please check the below code had problem

```
 DECLARE @Q1 VARCHAR(MAX)  
   SET @Q1='SELECT *  INTO ##FINAL  FROM 
    (SELECT [ASSIGNEDTO],LEFT([MONTH],3) AS [MONTH],[COUNT]  
    FROM #ASSIGNEE_TICKETSTATUS)A  
    PIVOT(SUM([COUNT])  
    FOR [MONTH] IN('+@COLUMNHEADER +'))B'  
   PRINT @Q1  
   EXECUTE(@Q1)                        

   SELECT * FROM ##FINAL
```

i can't write it as direct query it is not working when i wrote in directly, please anyone help

Comment: I would go with Actual tables instead of global Temp tables in azure.create once and truncate them prior to using them

Comment: As far as i can tell, global temp table is not supported in Azure SQL database. You would receive error 40516 **''Global temp objects are not supported in this version of SQL Server.'** when trying to create global temp table.